# Hand tool identification

Tags: hand-tools

[image]

I'm trying to identity the tool in the photo. The tablet is included for size, it has a 10.5 inch screen.

Comment: It looks like a spoon/bowl scoop but the handle makes me wonder. It has a single bevel. The ring where the hook comes out made of copper.

Answer (score 4):

That is a type of **hook knife**, commonly used to help hollow wooden spoons, bowls and *kuksa*.

[image: Hook knives]

<sup>**Source:** [Robin Wood](https://www.robin-wood.co.uk/wood-craft-blog/2013/01/29/best-spoon-carving-knife-hook-knife/).</sup>

While they have been and still are available commercially many such tools have been made by their users. We can't see the blade clearly enough to be able to guess which is the case here, but often there's no visible difference anyway.

The handle could easily be homemade, because it is mismatched to the tool — as you'll see if you look around more online and in spoon-carving books, hook knives typically have much smaller handles, for a single-handed grip as with most knives.

Although this one could have been made to provide a longer and fatter grip for some reason it very much looks like it could have been made for another purpose originally. It looks quite like some user-made handles for turning tools (sometimes gripped with two hands, or far back for leverage reasons) but immediately before I posted I realised it could just as easily be one of the pair of handles from garden shears!

We can't be sure from the photo whether it is missing its ferrule, a metal ring or cap used to reinforce the juncture between tool handle and blade. As you can see from the image I included not all hook knives actually need ferrules, but this handle was shaped for one to be fitted.

Comment: And hook knives aren't limited to woodworking, either. I think farriers have rather robust versions they refer to as "hoof knives" but it's basically the same thing.